# Need help to reduce the width on my buttons

Tags: javascript, html

my friend has designed my webpage for me, but has now gone on holiday and i only know the very basics.  I want to reduce the width of my buttons on one of my pages.

I think this is the part of the coding (where it says (".betbutton) i need to change but just don't know how - hope somebody can help me - thanks

```
$(".betbutton").click(function(){
$("#numberofbets").html(this.attributes["nob"].value);
bet = this.attributes["bet"].value;
```

This is the problem with how it actually looks on my site and need the size to reduce so the buttons all shift to the left.
http://freebetoffersonline.com/bet-calc.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the buttons with Chrome's Web Inspector you see that they have a dynamic width. The container, which has class name .bidlist has a fixed width of 880px. Change it to ~560px and you should be fine :-)

Comment: hi, thank you - unfortunately i can't see .bidlist anywhere in the coding

Comment: Thank you so much - once clicking on a button - the next stage was also the same problem but i have managed to sort than by finding the location in the css style and following what you said. How ever when i click the number of winners, the actual calulator itself could do with being shifted more to the left - could you kindly help me with this also

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If an answer solved your problem, make sure to check the tick on the left. Upvote any helpful question. If you have another, unrelated problem, open a new question. (But actually, if you want to relayout your pages, learn CSS first. This one is not as easy as the first one :P)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving you a fish I will teach you to fish.

First use [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and then install the [Firebug extension.](https://getfirebug.com/) Restart Firefox.

Once you have restarted there should be a Firebug menu, open it.

Once Firebug is open click on the blue arrow icon and that will let you choose the element inspector.

Then use the element inspector to inspect the "button" elements.

Firebug has a "style" tab on the right, it will show you the styles, including the `width` from various CSS classes. It will also show you where the CSS style sheet is located.

Even nicer, you can CHANGE the styles including the `width` to test and see if the changes you think may work will actually do what you think they will.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure which buttons you want to change the size of, so this answer will be rather generic.

You need to use CSS. Inside the HTML for your button put `style="width:100px;"` or whatever width you want. If there is already a `style` attribute in the button's HTML, just add the `width:100px;` to the style.

Answer (score 0):

In style.css, line 797, there is the `.bidlist width` property. Reduce that to something like   580px and see them shrink :)

Your friend made the buttons 25% of the width of the bidlist container, so there would be 4 fitting in each row. If you reduce the parent container's width, they shrink, too. In the style.css file, the design of all the elements are implemented, including the container width. So that is the part you change, not somewhere in the HTML (markup).

Comment: thank you, i have tried to change what you said, but i can't see .bidlist width - i only have 692 lines

Comment: You do: http://freebetoffersonline.com/css/style.css

Do not look in the PHP or JS file, in the CSS! There are multiple files that play a role in this, find the file `css/style.css`.

Comment: Thank you so much - once clicking on a button - the next stage was also the same problem but i have managed to sort than by finding the location in the css style and following what you said.

How ever when i click the number of winners, the actual calulator itself could do with being shifted more to the left - could you kindly help me with this also.

Comment: @ShaunAnnette, ask another question for that one. opatut solved your problem, so please accept his answer.